# Pipe a script into bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a difference between:

```
$ bash ~/script.sh
```

and:

```
$ cat ~/script.sh | bash
```

They seem to behave slightly differently, and I can't quite figure out what is going on.  My `script.sh` contains several lines of bash, but it seems to abort early when I pipe it into bash (but runs to completion when I run the script directly).

What's the difference in running the script in these two ways?

Furthermore, when I use `<`, the behavior is the same as the first example (runs to completion):

```
bash <( ~/script.sh )
```

The script is along the lines of

```
set -eux
ssh CLUSTER_0_SERVER_0 "do_something" || ssh CLUSTER_0_SERVER_1 "do_something"
ssh CLUSTER_1_SERVER_0 "do_something" || ssh CLUSTER_1_SERVER_1 "do_something"
```

Comment: Please also provide the contents of the `script.sh` file.

Comment: The script is pretty simple, does a `set -eux` then a few lines of `ssh CLUSTER_0_SERVER_0 "do_something" || ssh CLUSTER_0_SERVER_1 "do_something"` and then for another set of machines `ssh CLUSTER_1_SERVER_0 "do_something" || ssh CLUSTER_1_SERVER_1 "do_something"` etc (basically, it ssh's into a bunch of clusters and tries to run do_something on one machine in each cluster until a success, then it should move on to the next cluster).  I was confused by the difference in behavior between running it directly vs piping the script into bash on its stdin.

Comment: `bash <(foo.sh)` is **entirely** different from `bash <foo.sh`. The latter runs the script in a subshell, and feeds its stdout into the local bash.

Comment: Anyhow -- chances are good that something in your script reads from stdin. For obvious reasons this doesn't work so well when stdin is what's being used to read the script itself.

Comment: If you pipe the script into Bash, none of the commands in the script can meaningfully read from standard input unless you redirect the command's input.  The standard input was consumed by Bash itself.  (Or, at least, the first part of it was; there's a chance it doesn't read everything and leaves some stuff later in the script to be read by the command, but that leads to confusion -- if it happens at all.)

Answer (score 5):

Your ways of running the same script are all different in **semantics**.

See for example this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$
ssh 127.0.0.1
echo $$
```

Running it directly will execute all of the lines inside and both `echo` invocations will print the same PID: everything is a single process which runs the commands inside the script, one by one.

Running it via `cat ./script.sh | bash` creates two different processes in the beginning: one for doing the `cat` and one for `bash`. However, when the bash interpreter reads and executes the `ssh` command you get an error (if the ssh is not configured to not print it):

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

and then you get a login to the machine and it leaves immediately, **killing the current process**. Thus, the second value is a different PID. In your case, you have two `ssh` commands linked by a conditional operator. However, since after the first one the interpreter is killed there is no way the second command will be executed. That's why you'll get only the `*_SERVER_0` `ssh` commands executed.

The third case works but only by mistake. The `<( cmd )` construct means executing `cmd` and passing its output as a file argument to the caller. In your case, the script doesn't print anything so that's why you don't see any error. Running the example script you'll get errors like:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 1: 29355: command not found
```

The fourth case (suggested in the comments) `bash < script` is just the same as `cat script | bash`.

The **proper** way to run bash scripts is via `bash script` or `./script` (and shebang). If you want to run the instructions in the same process you can also use `. script` (`source`) All others might work or not, depending on some lucky side effects (in general they should not work).

Comment: or `. ./script`, which is "proper" but has different semantics.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't mention it just because of the different semantics.

Comment: The second value is a different PID because it's executed on the other side of the ssh connection by another process.